# Is it possible to trim some part of an canvas image before save as file by toDataURL?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I am saving a canvas as an image from my webpage. I used `html2canvas` to get that canvas (but I don't think this does matter)

Everything goes perfect but the layout of the image.

I need to trim the image like this:

[image: a short intro]

Is there any simple way that I can do this? For example something like this:

```
canvas.trim(0,15,canvas.width-30,canvas.height);
```

BTW, I want to do this with pure JavaScript.

Thanks for any kind of tips.

Comment: Show us your code...

Comment: the code is quite simple, just a standard html2canvas code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that, here is how I do it:

```
<script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<img id="img" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/LRVsxe5OJVY/maxresdefault.jpg">

<script>
    function saveMask() {
        var element = document.getElementById('img');
        html2canvas(element, {allowTaint: true}).then(h2c => {
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.height = 170;
            canvas.width = element.width - 300;

            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
            ctx.drawImage(h2c, -150, 0);

            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
        });
    }
    setTimeout(saveMask, 2000);
</script>
```